# What is the Hyperbole key combination to maximize only the height of the current frame?

Tags: hyperbole

What is the Hyperbole key combination to maximize only the height of the current frame?

The Hyperbole manual does not speak to this need. It has plenty of command bindings to widen, narrow, heighten, or shorten, but I could not find the key combination to just maximize the height, only, of the window, without also maximizing the width.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work by creating a button that calls a function like this?

```lisp
(defun my-maximize-height ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'fullscreen 'fullheight))
```

Comment: Maybe, but if I had to do that, then why would I use the Hyperbole? The question was about hyperbole. What you don't know about is that I can use elisp, and have for quite a long time now, and what I want to do is start using "standard" or even non-standard but readily available packages (such as Hyperbole), without having to reinvent their worlds in my personalized bag of Elisp tricks.